# Python Regular expression search specific string beside number

Tags: python, regex

I need help here. 
I have a list and string.

Things I want to do is to *find all the numbers from the string and also match the words from the list in the string that are beside numbers*.

```
str = 'Lily goes to school everyday at 9:00. Her House is near to her school. 
Lily's address - Flat No. 203, 14th street lol lane, opp to yuta mall, 
washington. Her school name is kids International.'

list = ['school', 'international', 'house', 'flat no']
```

I wrote a regex which can pull numbers

```
x = re.findall('([0-9]+[\S]+[0-9]+|[0-9]+)' , str,re.I|re.M)
```

Output I want:

```
Numbers - ['9:00', '203', '14th']
```

`Flat No.203` (because `flat no` is beside `203`)
`14` is also beside string but I dont want it because it is not contained in list.

But How can I write regex to make second condition satisfy. that is to search 
whether `flat no` is beside `203` or not in same regex.

Comment: Search for postive lookahead assertion in python regex. Will solve your problem

Comment: don't call your list `list` it's a type name.

Comment: `flat no` is not beside 203 because there is a separating dot. The problem 's specifications are unclear. Also `9:00` is not a number.

Answer (score 1):

There you go:

`(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2})|(?:No\. (\d+))|(\d+\w{2})`

Demo on Regex101.com can be found [here](https://regex101.com/r/pNCja2/1)

---

**What does it do and how does it work?**

I use two pipes (`|`) to gather different number "types" you want:

- First alteration (`(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2})` - captures time using 1-2 digits followed by a colon and another set of 1-2 digits (probably you could go for 2 digits only).
- Second alteration `(?:No\. (\d+))` - gives you the number prefixed with literal "No. " (note the space at the end), and then captures following number, no matter how long (at least one digit)
- The third and the last part `(\d+\w{2})` - simply captures any number of digits (again, at least one) followed by two word characters. You could further improve this part of the regex to match only `st`, `nd`, and `th` suffixes, but I will leave this **up to you**.

Also to get rid of further unneeded matches you could use lookarounds, but again - I'll leave this **up to you** to implement.

**General note** - rather than using one regex to rule... erm - match them all, you should focus on creating many simple regexes. Not only will this improve legibility, but also maintainability of the regexes. This also allows you to search for timestamps, building numbers and positional numerals **separately**, easily allowing you to split this information to specific variables.